# Zebra puzzle - Constraint Satisfaction in C

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, constraint-satisfaction

I'm trying to read up on constraint satisfaction problems and trying to code them to solve a few sample problems. I came across http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zebra_puzzle#C.2B.2B to solve the classic [zebra puzzle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle) In the C code given in rosetta code website, There was this following function. I have given only a few lines from it. I didn't know what the purpose of the two `if` statements is and how they worked.
Can someone explain it?

```
int checkHouses(int ha[5][5])
{
...
    int c_add = 0, c_or = 0;
    int m_add = 0, m_or = 0;
    int d_add = 0, d_or = 0;
    int a_add = 0, a_or = 0;
    int s_add = 0, s_or = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // Uniqueness tests.
        if (ha[i][C] >= 0) {
            c_add += (1 << ha[i][C]);
            c_or |= (1 << ha[i][C]);
        }
        if (ha[i][M] >= 0) {
            m_add += (1 << ha[i][M]);
            m_or |= (1 << ha[i][M]);
        }
        if (ha[i][D] >= 0) {
            d_add += (1 << ha[i][D]);
            d_or |= (1 << ha[i][D]);
        }
        if (ha[i][A] >= 0) {
            a_add += (1 << ha[i][A]);
            a_or |= (1 << ha[i][A]);
        }
        if (ha[i][S] >= 0) {
            s_add += (1 << ha[i][S]);
            s_or |= (1 << ha[i][S]);
        }
    }

    if ((c_add != c_or) || (m_add != m_or) || (d_add != d_or)
        || (a_add != a_or) || (s_add != s_or)) {
        return Invalid;
    }

    if ((c_add != 0b11111) || (m_add != 0b11111) || (d_add != 0b11111)
        || (a_add != 0b11111) || (s_add != 0b11111)) {

        return Underfull;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment actually explains it: they are verifying that there are no duplicate values between `ha[0..4][`x`]` for each value of x.

As to *how* it is doing it: each value is assigned a bit position, such that `1<<ha[i][`x`]` will yield a number with only the bit in that position set.  x`_or` will be the OR of those values, while x`_add` is their sum.  If there is a duplicate value, it will not have an effect on x`_or` (that bit is already set), but *will* on x`_add`; hence, they will be different.

Comment: Can it be done in some other more intuitive way? 
Say, I maintain an array where I update the values that have been used and check if there are any collisions?

Comment: Also, does the second if statement check if all values have been assigned?

Comment: There are all kinds of ways it could be done; intuitiveness is a bit of a judgement call.

Comment: Yes, the last `if` checks for all being assigned; you actually don't need the previous `if` unless you want to explicitly check for duplicate/bad values.